# euslisp advertise

Tags: ros, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to replace advertise-service function for the following subscribe.....
However, I can't complete it. Please help me.

(ros::roseus "add_two_ints_server")

(ros::advertise-service "add_two_ints" roseus::AddTwoInts #'add-two-ints)

(ros::subscribe "add_two_ints" roseus::AddTwoInts
#'(lambda (msg) (ros::rosinfo
(format nil  (send msg :data))))))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198720/euslisp-advertise/) by [Kuniaki Saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/20511/kuniaki-saito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`advertise-service` is a service, not topic. so you can not `subscribe` that topic. you can only `advertise-service`

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1